# Background image for a div containing other divs?

Tags: css

I can't seem to figure out why my header background will not show. I cut out a large amount of images and content in the html but here is my code - Please let me know if you know why my header image will not show. Thank you

Here is the html:

```
<DOCTYPE html>

<html lang='en'>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>fbgfbmgkfnf</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="test/css" href="css/style.css" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.18/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.timers-1.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.galleryview-3.0-dev.js"></script>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="js/jquery.galleryview-3.0-dev.css" />


</head>

<body>
<center>
<div id="header">
<div id="cf">
<a href="index.html">
  <img class="bottom" src="images/nav/home1.png" />
  <img class="top" src="images/nav/home.png" /></a>
</div>
</div>
```

And this is my CSS:

```
#header {
background-image: url(images/tweed1.png);
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a link?

Answer (score 0):

You need to go back a folder for your images. Change your CSS to the following.

```
#header {
background-image: url(../images/tweed1.png);
}
```

Comment: Well that was one solution. From your code, the CSS and images folders are in the same directory, meaning your other code wasn't going to work. Can you link me to your project?

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be a problem with the css-file:
Trying this will work, please try to add 'brackets' or change the url with something that exists like

htt*://jsfiddle.net/xbAGj/